# What’s a better way to say “lots of discussion”

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm drafting meeting notes from a steering committee that is attended by several c-more level executives.   What’s a better way to say “lots of discussion”

Comment: discussions /deliberations....

Comment: Maybe Exchanges...

Comment: @MystiSinha: You should make `deliberations` an answer. You'll have my upvote. ODO defines it as 'Long and careful consideration or discussion'

Comment: **Define "*better*".** You don't say what is limiting about the expression "*lots of discussion*", so there is no way for us to know what would constitute an improvement. This question should be closed as unclear (unless you clarify it).

Comment: I don’t know what a C-more level executive is, but it *does* have *executive* in there so maybe “enough hot air to run a small city was wasted before a decision was reached”. ;-)

Comment: After a **healthy discussion** with his advisors, Hitler decided to try to take Stalingrad in the late summer of 1942. It did not work out well for the Nazis.

Answer (score 9):

Try-*deliberations*.

> The noun **deliberation** comes from the Latin word deliberare,
>   meaning “weigh,” or “consider well.”
>
> Whenever a person or group needs to work through **all of the possible
>   solutions** to a problem, this is ***deliberation***.

- A mistrial was declared after 18 days of *deliberations*.

(Washington Times,Jun 1, 2015).

- He told reporters he couldn’t comment as he left the courtroom after
  a 13-hour day of testimony and jury *deliberations*.

(Time,May 30, 2015).

([vocabulary.com](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/deliberation))

Comment: +, I would prefer deliberations to "lot of ...." in a formal meeting note.

Comment: Here's my +1 as promised. Your link was a bit off. Fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd replace the more informal "lots of" by wide/considerable/in-depth/intense discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You might try **extensive discussion** or, if the discussion was extensive beyond reasonable limits, **exhaustive discussion**.

Answer (score 1):

If it got a little heated you could go for:

> "A full and frank exchange of ideas and concepts"

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context.

After *much discussion* ...

Lengthy discussion

Quantitative discussion

Answer (score 1):

Maureen, am I right that you are referring to CEOs, CFOs, CIOs and the like when  you say c-more level executives? At my organization we call those folks C-level. And I'm also guessing that you want to keep your meeting notes as professional and dispassionate as possible, and just stick to objective and accurate language.

If the discussion was productive and marked by participants' interest, excitement and energy, you might use the term **healthy discussion**.

If the discussion went long because of disagreements or confusing information that required clarification, you might say **debate and discussion**.

If the discussion was unfocused and not productive, you might want to tactfully leave it at **lengthy discussion**, or perhaps the overly flattering **brainstorming**, and not qualify too much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "discourse."

> Discourse(noun): A formal discussion of a topic in speech or writing.

**Example:**

> All listened devoutly to a discourse delivered with an emphatic slowness and penetrating beneath the letter of the Law to the spiritual truth that lay hidden within.

**Source:**
oxforddictionaries.com: [Discourse](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/discourse)

Comment: Neither of these imply *a lot* of discussion

Comment: Hi, and thanks for taking the time to post under this question. It's great that you want to help. However, this answer doesn't really seem to be a full answer. When answering it's best to write in full sentences and, in the case of [tag:single-word-requests], give a good explanation why the word you're suggesting is a good one. If necessary quote and reference a dictionary.

Comment: Done! Provided the source and an example.